# Does Ubuntu come with a reliable tool for migrating data from Windows?

Tags: windows, migration

I currently have Windows 10 on my computer, and I am planning on switching to Ubuntu.  I want to make sure my data are transferred safely from Windows to Ubuntu, without any data loss, corruption or other issues.  I read that Ubuntu has a built-in tool for migrating data from Windows.  I was wondering whether that is correct.  If so, then I was wondering whether the tool is 100% reliable.

I read about this tool at

https://www.computerworld.com/article/2540632/moving-from-windows-to-linux--here-s-how-to-take-the-good-stuff-with-you.html

As a separate issue, I understand that prior to installing Ubuntu, I need to back up all my data.  I am using a wizard to create a disk image on an external hard drive, with all the information from my computer.  I plan to make the external hard drive bootable, so I can reinstall Windows if necessary.  I plan to expand the image, so I can transfer data to Ubuntu.

Another issue for some people is that Windows applications do not automatically run on Linux.  However, I do not believe that should be an issue for me.  My only Windows-specific data are in Microsoft Office files.  I installed a Windows version of OpenOffice on my computer, and I verified that I could open my Microsoft Office files.  I know that OpenOffice does not have all of the features of Microsoft Office.  However, I did not create any files requiring special features.    Additionally, I understand that Wine (open source) and CrossOver (commercial software) can install and run Microsoft Office on Windows.  In a worst-case scenario, I could create a dual-boot system, with Ubuntu on one partition and Windows on another.

My only concern is about safely migrating my data from Windows to Ubuntu.  I was wondering whether the information I found about a built-in data migration tool on Ubuntu is accurate.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What "data" are you asking about? If you copy your personal files somewhere else, then install Ubuntu, you'll be able to copy them back. There is no need for a special tool for that.

Comment: And I never heard of "a built-in data migration tool on Ubuntu".

Comment: If you need features from Microsoft Office that are not available in Open Office you can also run Windows with MS Office in a Virtual Machine. And Linux reads and writes to NTFS partitions, so that won't be a problem. Also check out 'Lutris' for running Windows applications. If you know how to partition your disks, I advice dual booting for a while, until you are secure that you can run all the applications you need. Try Ubuntu first so know all your hardware is working.

Comment: On the Super User Stack Exchange site, I asked whether the rsync command provided a safe means of transferring data from Windows to Linux.  One of the users on that site told me that there could be possible issue, particularly with transferring text files.  Other users did not think this should be a problem.  If Ubuntu has its own data migration tool, then that might be the best route.  My question is at https://superuser.com/questions/1728926/does-the-rsync-command-provide-a-safe-means-of-transferring-data-from-a-windows

Comment: "The disk image created by a wizard" is unclear. It is unlikely that you'll be able easily restore files from there using Ubuntu. Why not copy your files without any images or wizards?

Comment: There is no single migration tool because there are so many possible sources of data. Don't rely upon developers to correctly guess what kind of data you have and where you keep it. Find out for yourself what you have and where it is. Make yourself a list. Follow that list when you migrate. Be prepared with a Plan B for when complex tools and wizards fail.

Comment: @Pilot6 I think I might have used the wrong terminology when I referred to a "disk image".  I believe a disk image is a compressed copy of everything on a disk.  I was referring to an expanded copy of everything.  I believe the correct term for an expanded copy might be a clone, rather than an image.

Comment: @Pilot6 I was originally planning on copying all my personal files from my computer onto flash drives, and then copying the flash drive data onto Ubuntu after installation. On the Super User Stack Exchange, I asked whether this was a safe way to transfer data, and someone told me it was not. That user recommended that I use dism. An error message came up when I tried to use dism. So, I decided to go with a wizard which came with an external hard drive. My Super User question is at https://superuser.com/questions/1724043/does-the-xcopy-command-on-windows-provide-a-safe-means-of-backing-up-data

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't have a "data migration tool from Windows to Linux".

But personal files (text, images, video, etc.) can be used in Ubuntu the same way as in Windows.

You can backup these files anywhere you like and then copy them to Ubuntu after installation.

Regarding MS Office files, most of them can be opened with LibleOffice without problems. But there are other office suits installable to Ubuntu that support MS files better.

Also MSOffice can be installed using wine or playonlinux.

Comment: As I mentioned, the following article claims that Ubuntu has built-in tools for migrating data from Windows: https://www.computerworld.com/article/2540632/moving-from-windows-to-linux--here-s-how-to-take-the-good-stuff-with-you.html The author of this article is a senior writer for Computerworld. So, I think he is reputable. However, the article is from 2007. So, perhaps it is outdated.